# Using Kusto scan() to determing start and end of a session

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a bunch of sequential telemetry data, stored in a single table, with only a `Timestamp` (indicating the start of the event) and the code (`reason_code`).

What I'd like to do is get the start and end timestamp for each of the *sessions*, where a session is a defined as a set of consecutive records with identical `reason_code`. The end timestamp is the timestamp of the next event with a different code.

Source data:

| Timestamp | reason_code |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-28 01:07:01.9840000 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 02:07:07.5330000 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 03:07:13.9510000 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 03:58:52.5190000 | 0 |
| 2023-02-28 04:58:57.9890000 | 0 |
| 2023-02-28 05:35:34.9820000 | 101 |
| 2023-02-28 05:35:44.9930000 | 1 |
| 2023-02-28 05:38:43.5760000 | 0 |
| 2023-02-28 05:55:24.1750000 | 0 |
| 2023-02-28 06:22:23.6230000 | 101 |
| 2023-02-28 06:22:33.6340000 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 06:28:48.0060000 | 102 |
| 2023-02-28 06:51:06.2370000 | 101 |
| 2023-02-28 06:51:10.2420000 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 06:55:28.4960000 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 06:57:56.6280000 | 102 |
| 2023-02-28 07:38:30.8380000 | 101 |

Desired outcome:

| start_ts | end_ts | reason_code | session |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-28 01:07:01.9840000 | 2023-02-28 03:58:52.5190000 | 4 | 1 |
| 2023-02-28 03:58:52.5190000 | 2023-02-28 05:35:34.9820000 | 0 | 2 |
| 2023-02-28 05:35:34.9820000 | 2023-02-28 05:35:44.9930000 | 101 | 3 |
| 2023-02-28 05:35:44.9930000 | 2023-02-28 05:38:43.5760000 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023-02-28 05:38:43.5760000 | 2023-02-28 06:22:23.6230000 | 0 | 5 |
| 2023-02-28 06:22:23.6230000 | 2023-02-28 06:22:33.6340000 | 101 | 6 |
| 2023-02-28 06:22:33.6340000 | 2023-02-28 06:28:48.0060000 | 4 | 7 |
| 2023-02-28 06:28:48.0060000 | 2023-02-28 06:51:06.2370000 | 102 | 8 |
| 2023-02-28 06:51:06.2370000 | 2023-02-28 06:51:10.2420000 | 101 | 9 |
| 2023-02-28 06:51:10.2420000 | 2023-02-28 06:57:56.6280000 | 4 | 10 |
| 2023-02-28 06:57:56.6280000 | 2023-02-28 07:38:30.8380000 | 102 | 11 |
| 2023-02-28 07:38:30.8380000 |  | 101 | 12 |

The [`scan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator) operator looks like a good fit, but after countless times reading the documentation and attempting queries, I can't seem to grasp it at all.

The only way I managed to do it so far, is using this query:

```
T
| scan with 
(
    step s1 output=all: isempty(s1.reason_code) or s1.reason_code != reason_code;
)
| extend EndTs=next(Timestamp)
| project-rename StartTs=Timestamp
```

I doubt very much this is optimal, and I'm sure there's a better way without needing `prev()`, relying on just `scan()`.

Suggestions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable (Timestamp:datetime, reason_code:int)
[
    datetime(2023-02-28 01:07:01.9840000), 4,
    datetime(2023-02-28 02:07:07.5330000), 4,
    datetime(2023-02-28 03:07:13.9510000), 4,
    datetime(2023-02-28 03:58:52.5190000), 0,
    datetime(2023-02-28 04:58:57.9890000), 0,
    datetime(2023-02-28 05:35:34.9820000), 101,
    datetime(2023-02-28 05:35:44.9930000), 1,
    datetime(2023-02-28 05:38:43.5760000), 0,
    datetime(2023-02-28 05:55:24.1750000), 0,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:22:23.6230000), 101,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:22:33.6340000), 4,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:28:48.0060000), 102,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:51:06.2370000), 101,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:51:10.2420000), 4,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:55:28.4960000), 4,
    datetime(2023-02-28 06:57:56.6280000), 102,
    datetime(2023-02-28 07:38:30.8380000), 10
]
| order by Timestamp asc
| scan  with_match_id=session with
    (
        step s1: reason_code != s1.reason_code;
        step s2 output=none: reason_code != s1.reason_code;
    )
| project start_ts = Timestamp, end_ts = next(Timestamp), reason_code, session = session + 1
```

The response will:

```
"start_ts","end_ts","reason_code","session"
"2023-02-28 01:07:01.9840000","2023-02-28 03:58:52.5190000","4","1"
"2023-02-28 03:58:52.5190000","2023-02-28 05:35:34.9820000","0","2"
"2023-02-28 05:35:34.9820000","2023-02-28 05:35:44.9930000","101","3"
"2023-02-28 05:35:44.9930000","2023-02-28 05:38:43.5760000","1","4"
"2023-02-28 05:38:43.5760000","2023-02-28 06:22:23.6230000","0","5"
"2023-02-28 06:22:23.6230000","2023-02-28 06:22:33.6340000","101","6"
"2023-02-28 06:22:33.6340000","2023-02-28 06:28:48.0060000","4","7"
"2023-02-28 06:28:48.0060000","2023-02-28 06:51:06.2370000","102","8"
"2023-02-28 06:51:06.2370000","2023-02-28 06:51:10.2420000","101","9"
"2023-02-28 06:51:10.2420000","2023-02-28 06:57:56.6280000","4","10"
"2023-02-28 06:57:56.6280000","2023-02-28 07:38:30.8380000","102","11"
"2023-02-28 07:38:30.8380000","","10","12"
```

Here, two steps are used to mark sessions [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator#sessions-tagging). Or you can add [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rownumberfunction) function in your example to number the sessions